# Use of IOIntensive in Apigee JavaCallouts

Tags: apigee

Should the IOIntensive Annotation be used in all referenced classes in an Apigee Edge Java Callout or just in the Class that implements com.apigee.flow.execution.spi.Execution

For Instance --

```
@IOIntensive
public class Apples implements Execution {

public ExecutionResult execute(MessageContext messageContext, ExecutionContext executionContext) {

  Fruit.giveMeWorms();
  return ExecutionResult.SUCCESS;
}

public class Fruit {

  public static final giveMeWorms(){
    //do something io intensive
  }
}
```

In this case should the Fruit class also use the IOIntensive attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate only the class, which is being referred by JavaCallout policy. No other Class should be annotated, else you will get Api Proxy error.

```
@IOIntensive
public class Apples implements Execution {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to usage of @IOIntensive:
I believe it makes sense to annotate only the classes which require kind of like a async behaviour to be annotated as 'IOINTENSIVE'. Because what internally happens is a separate light-weight thread gets assigned to do that, improving the overall performance of the application(apiproxy).

And as abhishek says, You should annotate only the class, which is being referred by JavaCallout policy. No other Class should be annotated, else you will get Api Proxy error.